# AllowedGrantTypes difference in Identityserver4 (in practice)

Tags: asp.net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I read [IdentityServer4 Documantaion](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html) about various **GrantType** it has.
but it could not answer this question: "Which **AllowedGrantType** should I choose for my project?"
. Can anybody explain me about practical usage of each GrantType?

**Additional Informaion:**

In my senario, I have a login app with **IdentityServer4**(let`s call it login-app), that is responsible for  user's login and three **ASP .Net Core** appliation that use it for authenticate users.
I want the user to not need to authenticate and login from app2 or app3 when the user is authenticated through the app1.
And if it logged out from one of the three apps, it logged out the other two.
Which **AllowedGrantType** should I use in **configuration** of identityserver4?

Answer (score 1):

Allowed grant types define the OAuth / OpenID Connect flows that the client application can use to authenticate itself/users.

If your applications are back-end ASP.NET Core applications, the Authorization Code grant type/flow makes the most sense.

Single Sign-On / Single Sign-Out should work fine with this flow in your case.